# filter rows on regular expression in column

Tags: r

I would like to filter the rows that contains upper case letters in the column `t3` The letters can be ATCG in different combination. Please look at my example and my try.

```
> head(dat)
                                      IsomiR freq start end mism   add t5 t3
1 hsa-miR-146b-5p_TGAGAACTGAATTCCGTAGGCTGTTT    1     9  32 16GA  I-TT  0 GT
2    hsa-miR-24-3p_TGGCTCAGTTCAGCAGGAACATTTT    1    50  71 22TG I-TTT  0  0
3       hsa-miR-140-3p_TACCACAGGGTAGGACCACGG    1    62  82 14GA     0  0  0

dat[dat$t3 =="ATCG",]
```

Comment: Maybe `dat[grepl("[A-Z]",dat$t3),]`?

Answer (score 5):

We can use `grep`

```
dat[grep('[ATCG]', dat$t3),]
#                                       IsomiR freq start end mism  add t5 t3
#1 hsa-miR-146b-5p_TGAGAACTGAATTCCGTAGGCTGTTT    1     9  32 16GA I-TT  0 GT
```

Or if it is nonspecific

```
dat[grep('[A-Z]', dat$t3),]
```